# How do I create my DataFrame to show only French movies in the 'Language' column of my dataset where there is multiple languages in the column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I create my DataFrame to show only French movies in the 'Language' column of my dataset where there is multiple languages in the column?

Example:

```
Languages column:
French
English
German,French,Spanish
Spanish,English,French
French, English, Gernman
```

What I have been trying only brings back the columns that have French only as the value in the language column.
Please help!

I have tried:

```
df.loc[df['column_name'] == some_value]
```

but it only returns movies that are in the French language only, not those that are in French but also in other languages.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with word boundaries (`\b`) to avoid matching substrings (e.g. 'Abc' matching 'Abcde'):

```
df.loc[df['column_name'].str.contains(r'\bFrench\b', case=False)]
```

If you are sure that there is no possible substring match (might be possible with languages):

```
df.loc[df['column_name'].str.contains('French', case=False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Loc function returns the data at the specified index.
You should get the rows you want like this:

```
df[df['column_name'] == 'value']
```

Comment: Have you read the question? ;)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If the Language column contains the laguages separated with commas, then you could split that string in `','` with `str.split(',')`, that returns a `list`, and then check if French is included in the list. You can check that with the `Pandas apply()` which can applies a function to each element of a column. [Pandas apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) has much more functionality and is very useful in general.

A working example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'languages': ['French', 'English', 'German,French,Spanish', 'Spanish,English,French', 'French,English,German']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['languages'])


def check_language(languages: str):

    lang_split = languages.split(',')
    res = 'French' in lang_split
    return res


df['French_included'] = df['languages'].apply(check_language)
```

or since check function is very simple you could just write this:

```
df['French_included'] = df['languages'].apply(lambda e: 'French' in e.split(','))
```

which returns

```
df
                languages  French_included
0                  French             True
1                 English            False
2   German,French,Spanish             True
3  Spanish,English,French             True
4   French,English,German             True
```

Of course, you can write the function to do whatever you like, for example to return French instead of returning `True` or `False`, or perform other checks as well, such as ignoring uper/lower case etc.